# How to avoid reusability of tableview cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When I click on select button at indexpath.row == 0 or any so , only  with respective "session label value" will change but here that will not happen.  it will change the below cell value also i.e. indexpath == 7 or 8 , I think here is reuse of cell so, how I can avoid it.

My code is like below.

1.UITableViewCell Class:

```
import UIKit

class DemoTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var mSelectButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var mDateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var mSessionLabel: UILabel!    

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

1. ViewController Class:-

   import UIKit

   ```
       class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

           var month_year = ""
           var fromYear = ""
           var toYear = ""
           var monthYearList = ""
           var monthYearListArray = [String]()
           let picker : UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()

           var from_date = ""
           var to_date = ""

           //
           var selectedTagValue = Int()
           var aSheetValue = ""
           var isFromActionSheet = Bool()
           var isFromFinalClick = Bool()
           var intArray = [Int]()

           @IBOutlet weak var mTableView: UITableView!

           // MARK:- ViewController Life Cycle Methods

           override func viewDidLoad() {
               super.viewDidLoad()
           }

           override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
               self.printDatesBetweenInterval(self.dateFromString("2017-07-01"), self.dateFromString("2017-07-12"))
           }

           //MARK:- UITableViewDataSource and Delegate Methods

           func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

               return monthYearListArray.count
           }

           func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

               let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DemoTableViewCell")! as! DemoTableViewCell

               cell.mDateLabel.text = monthYearListArray[indexPath.row]

               if isFromActionSheet{

                   if indexPath.row == selectedTagValue{
                       cell.mSessionLabel.text = aSheetValue
                       isFromActionSheet = false
                   }
               }

               cell.mSelectButton.tag = indexPath.row
               print("cell.mButtonOutlet.tag: \(cell.mSelectButton.tag)")

               cell.mSelectButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.actionOnSelectButtonClick(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

               if isFromFinalClick{
                   if cell.mSessionLabel.text == "Full Day"{
                       self.intArray.append(1)

                   }else if cell.mSessionLabel.text == "First Half"{
                       self.intArray.append(2)
                   }else{
                       self.intArray.append(3)
                   }
               }

               return cell
           }


           // MARK:- IBAction Methods

           func actionOnSelectButtonClick(_ sender: UIButton)  {
               let mButton : UIButton = sender
               selectedTagValue = mButton.tag
               print("selectedTagValue: \(selectedTagValue)")
               isFromActionSheet = true
               openActionSheet()
           }

           // Submit Button

           @IBAction func actionOnSubmitButton(_ sender: Any) {
               isFromFinalClick = true
               mTableView.reloadData()
               print("intArray list: \(intArray)")

           }

           // MARK:- Instance Methods

           func openActionSheet()  {

               // 1
               let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Select Session", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

               // 2
               let fullDayAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Full Day", style: .default, handler: {
                   (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
                   print("Full Day")
                   self.aSheetValue = "Full Day"
                   self.mTableView.reloadData()
               })

               let firstHalfAction = UIAlertAction(title: "First Half", style: .default, handler: {
                   (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
                   print("First Half")
                   self.aSheetValue = "First Half"
                   self.mTableView.reloadData()

               })
               let secondHalfAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Second Half", style: .default, handler: {
                   (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
                   print("Second Half")
                   self.aSheetValue = "Second Half"
                   self.mTableView.reloadData()

               })

               //
               let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: {
                   (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
                   print("Cancelled")
               })

               // 4
               optionMenu.addAction(fullDayAction)
               optionMenu.addAction(firstHalfAction)
               optionMenu.addAction(secondHalfAction)
               optionMenu.addAction(cancelAction)


               // 5
               self.present(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
           }


           // MARK:- Date_List Method

           func printDatesBetweenInterval(_ startDate: Date, _ endDate: Date) {
               var startDate = startDate
               let calendar = Calendar.current

               let fmt = DateFormatter()
               fmt.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

               while startDate <= endDate {
                   print(fmt.string(from: startDate))
                   self.monthYearList = fmt.string(from: startDate)
                   print("self.monthYearList: \(self.monthYearList)")
                   fmt.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
                   monthYearListArray.append(fmt.string(from: startDate))
                   startDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: startDate)!
               }

               print("monthYearListArray: \(monthYearListArray)")
               mTableView.reloadData()
           }

           func dateFromString(_ dateString: String) -> Date {
               let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
               dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

               return dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)!
           }

       }
   ```

Answer (score 6):

Rather than avoiding reusing cells make sure that all UI elements are always in a defined state

```
 if isFromActionSheet && indexPath.row == selectedTagValue{
     cell.mSessionLabel.text = aSheetValue
     isFromActionSheet = false
 } else {
     cell.mSessionLabel.text = [default value]
     isFromActionSheet = [default value]
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for solutiion...

Comment: but it will not work for more than one value..i.e when i select cell at 0 indexpath then session label value will set propery but when i want to change cell at indexpath = 2 or 3 or 4 .....it will changes the value of cell at 0 index path .......
i don't want it .....so what i can do...for it ...?

Comment: Once again, make sure that any `if` condition which changes the value of an UI element has also an `else` branch to assign a default value. It's like a Swift `switch` expression: The cases must be exhaustive.

Comment: For example If you change the text color from (default) black to red on a `true` condition you have to set the color explicitly to black if the condition is `false` because the next time the cell is reused the color will remain red even if the condition is `false`. All UI changes must be balanced.

Answer (score 0):

The correct thing to do is that you need to always set these UI element in `cellForRow`.

The reason is that `UITableView` is not preparing table view cells for display until the user is trying to scroll to that position(namely when user is trying to see that cell). So the idea of reusing cells is to keep some *cell template* in reused location so that in the next time, your phone does not need to create everything from scratch again. The only thing needed to do is to set the cell to correct state again. This will also make the scroll more smooth.

By setting UI element, I mean that you have to set value to your UI element on your cell every time when your `cellForRow` method is called. Look at this piece of your code

```
if isFromActionSheet{//What if this if is not called? Your cell.mSessionLabel will not get set
    if indexPath.row == selectedTagValue{//What if this if is not called? Your cell.mSessionLabel will not get set
        cell.mSessionLabel.text = aSheetValue
        isFromActionSheet = false
    }
}
```

If either of the two if statement is not true, then your mSessionLabel on your cell will not get new value, and may display some other value that is from the template cell. So you have to create two else statements add set mSessionLabel in the two else statement.

Comment: how to set UI element , if possible can u tell me in details?
thanks for ans......

Comment: @Kiranjadhav Updated